# Migrating & consolidating file shares to new server vm

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, network-share

An interesting little puzzle for you guys & gals:

My organization has 3 companies, each with their own separate hardware server and file storage, that we're looking to consolidate into our vm resources. Here's how much data is involved:

Company=  Department,  Users

O=        120 GB,      50 GB
P=        85 GB,       30 GB
R=        473 GB,      347 GB   (Huge GIS dataset files equaling 100 GB in BOTH dept. & users)
Additionally, software installer storage share equals 75 GB
Additionally, digital camera pictures storage share equals 70 GB

Ideally (and that is just an ideal), we'd have one vm Windows 2012 server to handle everything.

On our vm resource areas, we typically have 1TB or 2TB LUNs, so server volumes could only equate to 800GB or 1600GB each. I'm uncomfortable (perhaps needlessly) spanning volumes.

We don't want to cut the volumes down too small to necessitate a juggling act of file shares between volumes/servers and worrying about free space all the time, especially right off the bat of this consolidation.

NTFS cluster size shouldn't be much of an issue, as it is 4K for all volumes up to 16TB, right?

How would you guys set this up, if it was in your hands? What's your thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. This straddles the fence of a "primarily opinion-based" close reason.
2. If all 3 "companies" are either in the same domain or trusted domains why not setup DFS shares and maybe even DFS-R if necessary to each location?  You can still keep HQ as the source on a VM and just create a single 2TB LUN for now for all the data.  As the need expands, add a 2nd LUN and volume on the VM and continue to use DFS.  The clients will never know.  And if you are going the 2012 route, assuming you have the proc/memory resources available to the VM you could implement dedupe and save space.

Granted, that's just an opinion based on limited info.  You don't seem to have a space issue so something as simple as a single 2012 VM with everything on it (no DFS, no dedupe) and maybe (2) 2TB volumes would still more than suffice from what I can see.

You don't really go far enough into your environment, virtualization software in place, how the "companies" are setup, politics, need, bandwidth, # of users, existing issue(s), etc. to make anything beyond a simple opinion.